# permission denied when i try to get folder permission list

Tags: python, pywin32

i write this code, that suppose to show me permissions list of users and groups on specific file or folder

```
import os, sys
import win32api
import win32security
import ntsecuritycon as con
from sys import argv


script, FILENAME = argv

def show_cacls (filename):
  print
  print
  for line in os.popen ("cacls %s" % filename).read ().splitlines ():
    print (line)
open (FILENAME,'w')
print (show_cacls(FILENAME))
```

it work great with files, but when i try to run on folder i get this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tzuriel\Desktop\test.py", line 15, in 
    open (FILENAME,'w')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'd:/study'

i run from administrator user.

any idea?
TNX people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many things wrong as your question is a little vague. I'll try and list some possible issues.

In Windows paths you have to use backslashes '\'. In your error it looks like you are passing 'd:/study' which is not a valid Windows path.

You should not be using `os.popen` to call an external program. Please look at examples using the `subprocess` module, http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.

You could do something like:

```
import subprocess
import sys    

script, filename = sys.argv

output = subprocess.check_output(["cacls", filename]).splitlines()

for i in output:
    print(i)
```

There is no reason here to use a function here in a script file. I've also tried to follow standard Python (PEP8) formatting of variables, how to properly import modules, whitespace etc.